# Data Weave transformatio expcetion on JSON inbound message to Json outbound message

Tags: json, mule

I am trying to do the following transformation in data weave

```
%dw 1.0
%input in application/json
%output application/json
---
flowVars["xyz"]
```

"xyz" variable is itself a JSON object. I ask this because I need to merge two payload(payload + variable) as one JSON object , where this is the first step.

Also If I provide Payload instead of flowVars["xyz"] then I get the same error.The Payload is also of the same type JSON object.

The following is the stack trace

```
Root Exception stack trace:
com.mulesoft.weave.writer.json.JsonInvalidStructureException: JSON can only have one top-level value and that value can only be either an array or an object
at com.mulesoft.weave.writer.json.JsonWriter.value(JsonWriter.scala:44)
at com.mulesoft.weave.writer.json.JsonWriter.value(JsonWriter.scala:36)
at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.Engine.internalExecute(Engine.scala:88)
at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.Engine.execute(Engine.scala:53)
at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.Engine.execute(Engine.scala:181)
at com.mulesoft.weave.mule.WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler.write(WeaveMessageProcessor.scala:198)
at org.mule.transformer.simple.ObjectToString.createStringFromOutputHandler(ObjectToString.java:102)
at org.mule.transformer.simple.ObjectToString.doTransform(ObjectToString.java:56)
at org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:415)
at org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:366)
at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.transformMessage(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1606)
at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.applyAllTransformers(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1509)
at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.applyTransformers(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1487)
at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.applyTransformers(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1479)
at org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.process(AbstractTransformer.java:114)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:94)
at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:94)
at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56)
at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:102)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:94)
at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56)
at org.mule.construct.DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.process(DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.java:55)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:85)
at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:94)
at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56)
at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.processBlocking(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:58)
at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:94)
at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(Blocking...
```

---

Let me know if more information is needed

Comment: What's the content of the flowVar "xyz"?

Comment: According to the error "JSON can only have one top-level value and that value can only be either an array or an object", probably the value of flowVars["xyz"] is not valid.

Comment: @Shoki  "xyz" variable is itself a JSON object  . I have included in the question as well.

Comment: I have provided more clarity on the scenario

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the mime-type in your flowVar to `application/json`. 
You need to set it for your payload as well if it's not.

Comment: I see it is there already in the data weave component . When I give  payload instead of flowVars I get the same issue.